# When drawing spheres and lines at the same position, they are drawn at different places

Tags: 3d, three.js

As you can see [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cBfnj.jpg), I am trying to draw two tubes flanked on either side by spheres. While the first tube is drawn correctly, the second has its spheres drawn far away. For reference, the spheres are (in order) red, green, blue, and black.

Comment: What about the verifiable example? jsfiddle.net e.g.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My bad, I was applying the rotation to the sphere geometries *after* positioning them, so the spheres were being rotated around the origin.